# Backend Folder-Styles are gone after copy

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

In the backend in the sitetree we gave some folders a special style (edit folder -> Behaviour -> Contain Plugin -> News). So that this folders get the class `.t3-icon-pages-contains-news` and are blue.

Now I copied different typo3 files into that installation, but use the same database. Everything works fine, but this folders dont have the class `.t3-icon-pages-contains-news` anymore. The Behaviour -> Contain Plugin is still set to news.

Any ideas where this is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any code example so it is hard to figure out what is going wrong in your situation.

However, here a example how it should look like:

**typo3conf/ext/myext/ext_tables.php** or **typo3conf/extTables.php**

```
if (!$TCA['pages']['columns']['module']['config']['items']) {
    $TCA['pages']['columns']['module']['config']['items'] = array();
}

$TCA['pages']['columns']['module']['config']['items'][] = array('your label', 'myext', 'EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Icons/FolderIcon.gif');
\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Sprite\SpriteManager::addTcaTypeIcon('pages', 'contains-myext', '../typo3conf/myext/Resources/Public/Icons/FolderIcon.gif');
```